# How to pass parameters in API request in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am making an API call in react where from a cryptocurrency API data will be fetched. But I want to get the data for specific cryptocurrencies. I am trying to define some logic inside the fetch request but it's not working. I am trying to add "bitcoin" and "ethereum" as a paramters inside the request.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Crypto from './Component/Crypto';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        data: [
            {
                name:'',
                id:'',
                symbol:'',
                price_usd:'',
                percent_change_1h:'',
                percent_change_24h:'',
                percent_change_7d:'',
                isLoading:true
            },
        ]
    }
    this.fetchData=this.fetchData.bind(this);
}

fetchData=()=>{
  fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=3')
  .then((response)=>{
  const wanted=['ethereum','bitcoin']
  const r=response.data.filter(currency=>
    wanted.includes(currency.id))
    this.setState({
      data:r,
      isLoading:false
    })})
    .catch(err=>alert("error"));
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.fetchData();
  this.interval = setInterval (() => this.fetchData (), 10*1000)
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
      {this.state.isLoading?<Loading/>:
        <Crypto data={this.state.data}/>
      }
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Loading=()=>{
  return(
  <div>
    loading...
  </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: what is the final request url you want to make ?

Comment: I want data for the variable "wanted"

Comment: how do you want to pass values to wanted like `/https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?wanted=ethereum,bitcoin`

Comment: what is the URL you want to request ?

Comment: is `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/` provide support for `wanted` query parameter in their docs ?

Comment: No. I have defined wanted with values "ethereum" and "bitcoin". After that filtered the result from the response and added `wanted.includes(currency.id))`. In the raw data(link) id is "ethereum" and "bitcoin" so if it matched with wanted then it should display results of that.

Comment: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way :

```js
   
 fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=3')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data){
      const wanted=['ethereum','bitcoin']
      const filtered=data.filter(currency=>{                       return wanted.includes(currency.id)
      });
    console.log(filtered);
  }).catch(err=>alert('error'));
```

learn more about fetch api here : https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data